# Given a FirebaseListObservable object, how to get its path?

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

Given an `TASKS: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;` object, how can I get the path where it points to?

Tried `.$ref`, but I just see a bunch of obfuscated fields (in Chrome debugger).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has a bunch of obfuscated fields, but the function you want is implemented; it's on the prototype. You need to call [`toString`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#toString):

```
var url = TASKS.$ref.toString();
```

Comment: Your could also try `TASKS.$ref.path`.

Comment: @torazaburo Interesting, `path` appears to be a undocumented property (documented in the previous version of the SDK perhaps?) and calling `toString` on it does in fact return only the path.